# How to assign names to dynamically creating Objects in iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad, dynamic, uitextfield

I am creating an iPad app, in this I am dynamically creating the interface in the device, here is the code.

```
- (void)setUpInterface{
    UIScrollView *scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,self.view.frame.size.width-20, self.view.frame.size.height-20)];   

    int y = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < [labelArray count]; i++) {
        y=y+75;
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, y, 500, 30)];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[labelArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        [scrollview addSubview:label];

        UITextField *textBox = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, y, 500, 30)];
        textBox.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        textBox.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        [scrollview addSubview:textBox];
    }

    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width-100, y*2);
    scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
    scrollview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];

}
```

At the end when I click on a button I want to get the data entered in each text box separately. How can I implement that? How to assign names to each objects?
Thanks.

Comment: do you want to get the text in all texfields when you press a button? or you want to get a text in particular textfield when you press a button?

Comment: i want to get the text from  all the text fields when i press the button

Comment: use fast enumeration. posted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (UITextField *textField in [self.scrollview subviews])
{
    if([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
     {
        NSLog(@"text == %@", textField.text);
     }
}
```

Comment: thats a nice idea, but i only got the content in the last textbox

Comment: in your case   [scrollview subviews],just thought you might missed that.

Comment: i used     for (UITextField *textField in [self.scrollview subviews])
    {
        NSLog(@"text ==>%@",textBox.text);
    } but only the content from last textbox

Comment: sorry, i gave the name of my textbox. Now its working. Thanks :)

Comment: the code is getting not only the Textbox values but also the label box values. Why so? And the end i am getting an error, here is the log text ==>First text field
 text ==>1
 text ==>Number Field
 text ==>2
 text ==>True False Field
 text ==>3
 text ==>Option Field
 text ==>4
 -[UIImageView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a9b6d0

Comment: @John I edited my answer, im not on my mac right now so I can test the  codes. I think that would work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tag property. ie:

```
textBox.tag = 1;
textBox.tag = 2;
etc.
```

Unfortunately, these have to be integers, but you can make a map of integers to names if you want.

Comment: I edited by answer a bit. Don't use a tag of 0, because by default, all text fields will use 0 unless otherwise specified.

Comment: i can assign tag values to the textbox, but how can I get the string from textbox with each tag values?

Answer (score 0):

Make the text fields as member variable to access them from any method.

Comment: i afraid how to implement that?